# Magento 2 show additional message on Checkout Success Page

Tags: magento2, plugin

On the Checkout Success page, I want to show an additional message after `Your order is...`. I guess I can do that by an after method via plugin but I don't find the right method where to plug in. Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution for this. We should override the checkout success page in your custom theme: `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml`.

Or, we can reference the container `order.success.additional.info`

*{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
            <block class="{Vendor}\{Module}\Block\YourCustomBlock" name="onepage.success.custom" template="your_custom_template.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a magento 2. I am trying to solve it with a Plugin

Comment: Which Plugin method you tried?

Comment: No one tried yet, I would like to know where to hook in. I guess I need the method responsable for the ouput on the success page. With the same approach I added an additional message when a product was added to the cart.

Comment: Which Plugin you used for the Product?

Comment: there in my custom Plugin I use afterSetCustomerDataAsLoggedIn an add a success message

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh why the phtml rendered twice? first in the right place and second is rendered after footer?